# skip first duplicate record and update others

Tags: mysql, sql

Query 1: check if duplicate records exist:

```
SELECT
    id , username, COUNT(*)
FROM
   tbluser
GROUP BY
   username
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Result:

[image: duplicate records]

Query 2: Moniter duplicate records against one dataset.

```
select * from tbluser where username = 'abcuser1';
```

Result:

[image: duplicate record]

Query 3: (based on data in query 2, skip first record i.e, 293 and update status for all other duplicate occurrence.

**My current approach to skip first duplicate record and update others:**

```
    SELECT CONCAT(id , ',') 
FROM    tbluser u1
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    tbluser u2
        WHERE   u1.username = u2.username and u1.status = u2.status = 1 and u1.appId = u2.appId 
        LIMIT 1, 1
        )
        limit 1, 18446744073709551615
```

Above query give me the ids of duplicate records whose status needs to be updated. And then I paste the above result ids into:

```
update tbluser set status = 0 where id in (1,2);
```

Query 3 doesn't give desired result. It just skip first record and give all other duplicate records of all data sets.

> How can I skip the first duplicate record from each dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way:

```
UPDATE tbluser t
JOIN (
   SELECT username, MIN(id) AS min_id
   FROM tbluser
   GROUP BY username
) AS g ON t.username = g.username AND t.id <> min_id
SET status = 0;
```

The above query updates all records having an `id` value that is greater than the minimum `id` within a `username` slice.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c164cc/1)